# Delete first n digits from a column

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe(roughly 7000 rows) that looks as follows:

```
Col1    Col2
12345   1234
678910  6789
```

I would like to delete the first 4 digits from col1, so as to end up with:

```
Col1   Col2
5      1234
10     6789
```

Or just separate the first column in 2 columns.

Comment: do you mean `df['Col1'].astype(str).str[4:].astype(int)` assuming the dtype is int already

Comment: First 2 values: 12345, 678

First 2 digits: 12, 67

Answer (score 3):

Separating first column into two new ones:

```
In [5]: df[['New1','New2']] = (df['Col1'].astype(str)
                                         .str.extract(r'(\d{4})(\d+)', expand=True)
                                         .astype(int))

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
     Col1  Col2  New1 New2
0   12345  1234  1234    5
1  678910  6789  6789   10

In [9]: df.dtypes
Out[9]:
Col1    int64
Col2    int64
New1    int32
New2    int32
dtype: object
```

**NOTE:** this solution will work with Pandas version 0.18.0+

Comment: Hey Max, I get the following error:TypeError: extract() got an unexpected keyword argument 'expand'

Comment: @AndreiCozma, you must be using really old version of Pandas... What is your Pandas version?

Comment: 'pandas 0.17.1'

Comment: @AndreiCozma, try to omit `expand=True`. I can't test it against Pandas 0.17.1. PS it does make sense to update your Pandas version, as Pandas gets tons of new features and bug fixes with every new version. The actual version is 0.19.0